# Python get summertime breakpoints

Tags: python, time

I am new in Python, but I think this is an easy problem. I am parsing through a txt log file: timestamp value, timestamp value, and so on...

I am saving the data in a database with UTC time because otherwise there is one hour each year where I would have two values per timestamp (the hour when we switch from summer- to wintertime).

My question is, how can I get a timestamp for the last Sunday in March? I tried something like this:

```
x = 2014
ts_raw = x, 3, 31 - int(time.strftime("%w", (x, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))), 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
ts = time.mktime(ts_raw)
```

Doesn't look very elegant and doesn't work too... because this part:

```
time.strftime("%w", (x, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

This always returns 1...

I think there must be a much better way to do this... so please can someone post a few lines of code?

Comment: Looks like it always returns one because you always pass `0` as the value of `tm_wday`, the sixth element of your tuple.

Comment: i don't see your timestamps here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most concise solution, but citing the [zen of python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Explicit is better than implicit.*

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import calendar
import time

last = date(2014, 3, 31)
delta = (last.weekday() - calendar.SUNDAY) % 7
lastsunday = last - timedelta(days=delta)            # 2014-03-30
print time.mktime(lastsunday.timetuple())
```

[Here](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2014&month=3&country=1) a calendar for March 2014.